# LibGDX How to get mouse coordinates in the world?

Tags: java, libgdx

I've been looking for an answer for a long time, but I can't find it.
I use:

```
public Vector2 getWorldPositionFromScreen(Vector3 v){
    Vector3 vc = orthographicCamera.unproject(v);
    return new Vector2(vc.x, vc.y);
}
```

But the problem is that the y coordinate is flipped and I don't know how to flip it back. I tried the following methods, but none of them worked:

```
public Vector2 getWorldPositionFromScreen(Vector3 v){
    int screenHeight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
    Vector3 vc = orthographicCamera.unproject(new Vector3(v.x, screenHeight - v.y, v.z));
    return new Vector2(vc.x, vc.y);
}
```

I tried debugging and realized that Gdx.input.getX() and ...getY() return coordinates relative to the window, not the screen [image]
but nevertheless camera.unproject copes with this, in addition to vertical inversion. But I figured out that the inversion comes from Gdx.input.getY()

Comment: LibGdx uses a Y-up coordinate system. So the zero-point you marked in your image is not in the upper left, but in the lower left corner, and the Y-axis increases to the up-direction. It is easier to use this coordinate system than to flip the y-coordinate, because it is used everywhere in libgdx.

Comment: @Tobias I every update displayed the value "Gdx.input.getY()" and saw this result

Comment: @Tobias https://imgur.com/a/joXtUop

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it worked. The code I am using:

```java
@Override
public void render(){
    
    Vector3 mouseAtScreen = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(),  Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
    Vector2 mouseAtWorld = getWorldPositionFromScreen(mouseAtScreen);
    spriteBatch.draw(cursorPointTexture, mouseAtWorld.x, mouseAtWorld.y, 5, 5);
}
public Vector2 getWorldPositionFromScreen(Vector3 v){
    Vector3 vc = orthographicCamera.unproject(new Vector3(v.x,   v.y, v.z));
    return new Vector2(vc.x, vc.y); 
}
```